# A God turns himself into a mortal to meet a woman who considers herself unworthy of meeting a deity

Tags: story-identification, books

The mythology is that a God sees a women from his horse. She is beautiful and he must have her! She says she is unworthy to  meet him so he turns himself into a mortal.  Country is either England, Ireland or Scotland.

Can anyone identify this book?

Comment: What “book info” do you want?  If you mean that you want to know its name, see [How to ask a good story-ID question?](//scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482)

Comment: Can you remember anything else about the book? What year (approx) did you read it, was it new then or did it feel older? Was it long? Was it a collection of stories or one novel, what did the cover look like, what country were you in when you read it? ANY OTHER DETAIL you can remember that will help people place this book.

Comment: The book was one I heard about and is based on mythology in England, Ireland or scottland. The God comes down to hunt and upon seeing the beautiful women he turns himself into a mortal then eventually takes her back to the sky to live forever. It is probably an older book?